# Catching hibernate exception SqlExceptionHelper

Tags: hibernate, jpa

We are getting the exception in the log as below line, when the column is not matched with database column. But it is not throwing the exception. I have even kept the try catch. How can i catch the exception?

WARN  2015-11-04 17:25:44,055 [http-apr-8080-exec-4][SqlExceptionHelper.java:144] : SQL Error: 904, SQLState: 42000
ERROR 2015-11-04 17:25:44,055 [http-apr-8080-exec-4][SqlExceptionHelper.java:146] : ORA-00904: "SH_RATE_DESCRIPTIO": invalid identi
fier

```
 import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
 import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

 import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

 import com.core.model.entity.ShippingTable;

 @Repository("sTableDAO")
 public class STableDao {


 @PersistenceContext(unitName = "somaUnit")
 private EntityManager entityManager;


 public STable save(STable sTable) {    
    try{
        sTable = entityManager.merge(sTable);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return sTable;      
 }  
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`Level.FATAL` even swallowed the error log message. Setting

```
org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper")
    .setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

In a `static` initializer block of some arbitrary class did the trick!

Answer (score 2):

Try to get message from DataIntegrityViolationException

```
catch (DataIntegrityViolationException ex) {
   handleException(ex.getRootCause().getMessage()) /*get the message and handle it*/
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just set the loglevel for this logger to fatal.
In the code:

```
private static Logger logger = org.apache.log4j.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper");
logger.setLevel(Level.FATAL);
```

Or:

```
...
<!-- ADDED THE FOLLOWING -->
<logger category="org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper">
<level name="FATAL"/>
</logger>
...
```

Comment: Downvote, as this just hides the exception rather than allowing it to be caught/investigated. Question did not ask to hide the exception.

Comment: @bitcoder It doesn't hide the exception, it just prevents this class from printing the log message. The exception is still thrown

Comment: @selalerer The question being asked is "How can i catch the exception?". Not 'How can I prevent printing the log message'. This does not answer "How can i catch the exception?". 
(preventing printing is 'hiding' the exception, not catching it, and will also hide the error messages for any other columns that have this problem)

Comment: Just because I saw your comments: increasing the loglevel may help him to find the swallowed Exception. The other hint would be an exception breakpoint ...