# Prevent hibernate from logging `Unique Constraint Violation` messages

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am handling the `DataIntegrityViolationException` thrown by Hibernate, but would however prefer if Hibernate also did not log this message as an error.

```
2022-01-15 15:48:31.108  WARN 47319 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 23505, SQLState: 23505
2022-01-15 15:48:31.108 ERROR 47319 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Unique index or primary key violation: insert into ...
2022-01-15 15:48:31.109  INFO 47319 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] o.h.e.j.b.internal.AbstractBatchImpl     : HHH000010: On release of batch it still contained JDBC statements
```

Is there any way to prevent this from being logged?

Comment: Can you please show me your entity and insert query?

Comment: The entity has a unique column. I want to handle the case where a duplicate value is inserted.

Comment: You can set the logLevel as the guys did here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33521595/catching-hibernate-exception-sqlexceptionhelper

Comment: Thanks. This seems to be the only solution.